# Product Duplicate - Product image is duplicating twice

Tags: magento-1.9, product, product-images

We have written code to create product. Once a new product is created a duplicate of newly created product is generated. the code is as follows.

```
public function enableMasterProduct($product_code, $product_id){            

        $product = Mage::getModel ('catalog/product')->load($product_id);                           

        $masterProducts = Mage::getModel ('catalog/product')
                            ->getCollection()
                            ->addAttributeToFilter ( 'is_master_record', 1 )
                            ->addAttributeToFilter ( 'productcode', $product_code); 

        $pCount = $masterProducts->getSize ();

        if ($pCount == 0) {
            $newProduct = $product->duplicate();
            $newProduct->setStatus(2);
            $newProduct->setSku('master_'.uniqid());
            $newProduct->setData('group_price',array ());
            $newProduct->setIsMasterRecord(1);
            $newProduct->setSellerId(0);                        
            $newProduct->setProductcode($product_code);
            $id = $newProduct->getId();         
            $stockItem = Mage::getModel('cataloginventory/stock_item')->loadByProduct($id);
            if ($stockItem->getId() > 0 and $stockItem->getManageStock()) {
                $qty = 1;
                $stockItem->setQty($qty);
                $stockItem->setIsInStock((int)($qty > 0));
                $stockItem->save();
            }
            $newProduct->getResource()->save($newProduct);
        }

    }
```

This code works and a new product is generated. However the product image generated twice even though there is only one product image.

Answer (score 2):

You have to clear media gallery before save:

```
$newProduct->setMediaGallery(array());
```